# Multiple workflows for upcoming expiry date

Tags: date, sharepoint, workflow, designer

I'm new to Sharepoint and trying to word this in the best way.

I want to create a workflow for each created List items where it will send a notification to a person 'x' days (say 30 days) before expiry date.

For each same created List items, it will send another notification to person 'x' days (say 10 days) before expiry date.

So basically 2 workflow notifications.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Workflows are a set of tasks that are executed usually when an item is modified/created or when a user click on "launch workflow" (you can use workflows for your project but that's not the proper usage).

I would suggest you to look around the timer jobs which you can run for example every day to check every items of your two lists and send notifications accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you have only one list with a column "ExpiryDt" of type Date Time. And you can achieve it using only one list workflow...

Create a List Workflow on your list using SPDesigner and follow the steps listed below.

This is how it works:

1. Create a Workflow variable "DateToSendFirstReminder" as Date Time Type
2. Add an action "Add Time To Date" and in the "days" portion give value "-30". Here you are adding "-30" to your expiry date field(expiry date - 30 days) and sending the output to the workflow variable "DateToSendFirstReminder"
3. Then add an action "Pause Until Date" and set the "Date" value to "DateToSendFirstReminder" workflow variable
4. Now send reminder to the corresponding people(Send Email Action)
5. Add an action "Pause For Duration" and pause the workflow for 20 days, i.e. expiry date - 10 days.
6. Now send reminder to the corresponding people(Send Email Action)

Make the workflow run on creation of the item.
You can create one more variable and set a negative value of(number of days before expiry).
Add that value to your expiry date.
And tailor the above workflow according to your values..

**  *** Updated Answer *** **

Sorry for the delay. When I answered last time I don't have enough reputation to upload an image.
Now the WF logic shown in the below image will do the job...

[image: Workflow Logic]

Since you have so many list having the same fields, follow the below steps..

1. Create a content type with all required columns including the 'ExpiryDt'
2. Attach the content type to all the lists you have.
3. Create a reusable WF (SP2010 WF) that associates with the content type.
4. And configure the workflow so that it triggers when item gets created and 
   an existing items gets modified
   That's all...

**How it works..??**
When an item is created this WF starts and when the expiry date changes
the instance of the WF that started as a result of item creation will stop
and a new instance of the same workflow starts as a result of item update.

**Small catch:**
The WF gets triggered irrespective of the field change.
Even though the changed field is not the 'Expiry Date'..
So plz update the logic that handles this also.. becoz
we don't want more than one instance of the same WF..

Comment: Thanks this is very helpful! Although, I have multiple lists that has the same items but just with different views. Will this method still be applicable in setting reminders? Also, say the owner modifies the expiry date (to indicate the new expiration date), can this workflow still action automatically?